How can I display footprint in PcbDoc?
The following is a snippet. I have tried to attached footprint to schematics in Altium.

But this DIP wouldn't show up in PcbDoc when I executed the changes. And Altium suggested me removing this footprint.


This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

you need to draw a footprint where the numbers of the pads of the footprint and the pin numbers of the schematic of the component match each other, then if you add this footprint to the schematic of the component, you can see the footprint on the bottom left by clicking twice on the component on the schematic of the pcb and selecting the show footprint option
